A Problem On Differentiable Function
Q. Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with $f(0) = 0$. It $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, 1 \lt f'(x) \lt 2$. Then which of the following statements is true on $(0,\infty)$?
(A). $f$ is unbounded.
(B). $f$ is increasing and bounded.
(C). $f$ has at least one zero.
(D). $f$ is periodic function.
Solution: My attempt is,
Take a general linear polynomial function
$f(x)=ax+b$
Such that $f(0)=0 \Rightarrow b=0$
Since $1 \lt f'(x) \lt 2$
So $1 \lt a \lt 2$
$f(x)=1.5x$
Hence Option b,c,d discarded.
But how to check option A please help me thanks in advance.

You only have conditions on $f$, you can't just pick some subset of $f$ (such as the affine collection that you have chosen above). Also, the mean value theorem shows that the graph of $f$ lies strictly in-between the lines $x \mapsto x, x \mapsto 2x$.

@copper.hat: The way these questions usually work (but are poorly worded to convey that) is that one or more options are always true, while the other options are always false under the conditions stated. Assuming that is how that works, finding one counterexample for a possible option disproves it.  These questions get much harder when "true for some, but not all valid $f$" is an option. Then one counterexample isn't enough to distinguish between the new option and "always false".

@Robert Shore, Thank you very much Sir. I really appreciated it.

I think you are missing my point. Your solution just deals with a linear (well, affine) function. However, that is only one of many functions that satisfy the hypotheses in the question. you are supposed to validate the results for all such $f$ or provide a counterexample. So, your collection of $f$s can at best provide counterexamples.

My previous affine function examples can indeed serve as potential counterexamples, but I should not have stopped there.
Thank you for pointing out the oversight! I'll strive to provide more comprehensive and rigorous solutions moving forward.

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$.  Then in the interval $(0, \infty)$ we have $g'(x)=f'(x)-1 \gt 1-1=0$, so $g(x)$ is strictly increasing in that interval.
Since $g(0)=f(0)-0=0, \forall x \in (0, \infty)$ we have $g(x)=f(x)-x \gt 0$, so $f(x) \gt x.$
Thus, $f(x)$ is unbounded on $(0, \infty)$.
